# How to fix route is not defined when I register the route slash web.php using [ Laravel version 5.8 ]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have problem regarding register the route of slash in web.php, it gives me error that my route is not defined. `Route [/] not defined.` is there way to register my slash to the web.php? my main point here is when the user access the url http://localhost:8000/ the redirection will go to the index controller.

I will share to you guys my controller and my web.php

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index() {

    return view('index')
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

   <!--  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="{{asset('assets/W4_Double_bucket_EN.jpg')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="{{asset('assets/BBQ_Big_Crunch_Banner_en.jpg')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </div>

        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

  <br><br><br> -->

    <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
  <div id="wrapper" >

    <!-- Sidebar -->

    <!-- End of Sidebar -->


      <div class="container-fluid">
          <br><br><br><br>
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="{{asset('assets/W4_Double_bucket_EN.jpg')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="{{asset('assets/BBQ_Big_Crunch_Banner_en.jpg')}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>

            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
          <br><br><br>                   
            <div class="row">




              <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="card shadow ">
                      <div class="card-header bg-danger">
                          <b style=" font-weight: 500; font-size:14px; color:white;"><i class="far fa-comments"></i> Recent Posts</b>
                      </div>

                      <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-size:15px; font-weight: 400; color:black;">Special title treatment</h5>
                          <p class="card-text" style="color:#757a91; font-size:14px;">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                          <hr></hr>
                      </div>

                  </div>
                  <br/>
                  <div class="card shadow">
                      <div class="card-header  bg-danger" >
                          <b style=" font-weight: 500; font-size:14px; color:white;"><i class="far fa-user"></i> RGM Corner</b>
                      </div>

                      <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title">
                              <div>

                                  <h5 class="card-title" style="font-size:15px; font-weight: 400; color:black;">Special title treatment</h5>

                                  <div class="postDate" style="font-size:11px; color:#999;">2d ago</div>
                              </div>
                          </h5>
                           <p class="card-text" style="color:#757a91; font-size:14px;">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                           <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#757a91; font-size: 13px;"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;"></i> 2 Likes</a>

                          <hr></hr>
                          <br/>
                           <h5 class="card-title">
                              <div>

                                  <h5 class="card-title" style="font-size:15px; font-weight: 400; color:black;">Special title treatment</h5>

                                  <div class="postDate" style="font-size:11px; color:#999;">2d ago</div>
                              </div>
                          </h5>
                           <p class="card-text" style="color:#757a91; font-size:14px;">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                           <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#757a91; font-size: 13px;"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;"></i> 2 Likes</a>
                          <hr></hr>
                      </div>

                  </div>
                 <br><br>
              </div>


              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="card shadow ">

                      <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-title">
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-1"> <img src="{{asset('assets/rounded_image.jpg')}}" style="height:40px;,width:40px;" class="rounded-circle" alt="..."/></div>
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div style="line-height: 1.3;">
                                          <div class="postName" style="color:#900; font-weight: 500; font-size:14px;">Ronald Perpekto</div>
                                          <div class="postPosition" style="font-size:12px; color:#999;">Operations</div>
                                          <div class="postDate" style="font-size:11px; color:#999;">2d ago</div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <hr></hr>
                          </p>
                          <p class="card-text" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;">As a pre-emptive measure to ensure the safety of our people most especially our students, from the onslaught of Typhoon Tisoy that is predicted</p>
                          <p class="card-text">
                              <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('assets/BBQ_Big_Crunch_Banner_en.jpg')}}"></img> 
                          </p>


                      </div>
                      <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                           <div class="row">

                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <div class="row">
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;"></i> 2 Likes</a>
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#757a91; font-size: 13px;"><i class="far fa-comments" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;"></i> 50 Comments</a>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <br/>
                  <div class="card shadow">

                      <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-title">
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-1"> <img src="{{asset('assets/rounded_image.jpg')}}" style="height:40px;,width:40px;" class="rounded-circle" alt="..."/></div>
                                  <div class="col-md-4">
                                      <div style="line-height: 1.3;">
                                          <div class="postName" style="color:#900; font-weight: 500; font-size:14px;">Ronald Perpekto</div>
                                          <div class="postPosition" style="font-size:12px; color:#999;">Operations</div>
                                          <div class="postDate" style="font-size:11px; color:#999;">2d ago</div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <hr></hr>
                          </p>
                          <p class="card-text" style="color:#757a91; font-size:13px;">As a pre-emptive measure to ensure the safety of our people most especially our students, from the onslaught of Typhoon Tisoy that is predicted</p>
                          <p class="card-text">
                              <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{asset('assets/W4_Double_bucket_EN.jpg')}}" style="height:40,width:40"></img> 
                          </p>


                      </div>
                      <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                           <div class="row">

                               <div class="col-md-6">
                                  <div class="row">
                                       <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#757a91; font-size: 13px;"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up" style="color:#757a91; font-size: 13px;"></i> 2 Likes</a>
                                      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="color:#757a91; font-size: 13px;"><i class="far fa-comments" style="color:#757a91; font-size: 13px;"></i> 50 Comments</a>
                                  </div>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-md-3">

                 <div class="card shadow">
                      <div class="card-header bg-danger">
                        <b style=" font-weight: 500; font-size:14px; color:white;"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> What's Happening </b>
                      </div>

                      <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-size:15px; font-weight: 400; color:black;">Special title treatment</h5>
                          <p class="card-text" style="color:#757a91; font-size:14px;">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                          <hr></hr>
                      </div>

                  </div>
                  <br/>
                  <div class="card shadow">
                      <div class="card-header bg-danger">
                       <b style=" font-weight: 500; font-size:14px;  color:white;"><i class="far fa-file"></i> Recommended Pages</b>
                      </div>

                      <div class="card-body">

                          <p class="card-text">
                              <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fa fa-bicycle fa-2x" style="background: #f3f3f3; padding:9px; border-radius: 50%;"></i></div>
                                 <div class="col-md-9">
                                   <div style="line-height: 1.3; margin-left:0px;">
                                      <div class="postName" style="font-weight: 400; color:black; font-size:15px;">Hiflyer Website</div>
                                      <div class="postPosition" style="font-size:12px; color:#999;">https://www.hiflyer.ca/</div>
                                      <div class="postDate" style="font-size:11px; color:#999;">2019</div>
                                  </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>

                          </p>

                          <p class="card-text">
                              <div class="row">
                                 <div class="col-md-2"><i class="fas fa-desktop fa-2x" style="background: #f3f3f3; padding:9px;  border-radius: 50%;"></i></div>
                                 <div class="col-md-9">
                                   <div style="line-height: 1.3; margin-left:0px;">
                                      <div class="postName" style="font-weight: 400; color:black; font-size:15px;">Customer Display</div>
                                      <div class="postPosition" style="font-size:12px; color:#999;">https://icweb.hiflyer.ca/CustomerDisplay</div>
                                      <div class="postDate" style="font-size:11px; color:#999;">2019</div>
                                  </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>

                          </p>

                      </div>

                  </div>

                  <br/>

                   <div class="card shadow">
                      <div class="card-header bg-danger">
                        <b style=" font-weight: 500; font-size:14px; color:white;"><i class="far fa-calendar"></i> Upcoming Events </b>
                      </div>

                      <div class="card-body">
                          <h5 class="card-title" style="font-size:15px; font-weight: 400; color:black;">Special title treatment</h5>
                          <p class="card-text" style="color:#757a91; font-size:14px;">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                          <hr></hr>
                      </div>

                  </div>
                  <br/>
              </div>




      </div>


    </div>



  </div>
  <!-- End of Page Wrapper -->



  <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
  <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>




  <br><br><br><br>


@endsection
```

**Error:**

[image: Route not defined]

Comment: show you URL . also is it a get request

Comment: my url is localhost:8000, so when i try to access it, my route is not defined.

Comment: and how you are serving your project?

Comment: Please run this `php artisan route:list` and paste the response over here.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `index.php` file you've added `{{ route('/') }}` but in `web.php` file there is no route as the same name.

So, replace `{{ route('/') }}` to `{{ route('index') }}` in index.php file.

Or with url you can define it as below.

```
{{ url('/') }}
```

check with this change

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

Comment: Why the `/` in `route('/index')`? I don't think that this would work.

Comment: `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('index');` in this he defined `name('index')` now if you want to call then you must pass as `route('index')` if you go with url then you can define `{{ url('/')}}` that's okay. I hope you get my point.

Comment: Yes, I get the point. With `url('/')` it's okey but before with `route('/index')` this would have been working.

Comment: can you explain more, I didn't get your point on that, my goal is when the user try to access localhost:8000/ only the redirection must be on the index

Comment: when i use this function my route is working Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Comment: give the `->name('home')` instead of `->name('index')` or have you defined the `route('/')` anywhere?

Comment: @DilipHirapara i didn't define any route('/') anywhere of my project.

Comment: there is no route('/') in index.php file check layout.app file with included files like header,footer, sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your `index.blade.php` file you are using a route link like this `route('/')` and thats wrong (in your case).

In the `route()` function you need to enter the url name (in your case 'index') instead of the url path. So if you change `route('/')` to `route('index')` it work's.

Comment: when I used this function my route is working Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Comment: Post your `index.blade.php` file! As you can read in the error message the `route` function of the url generator tries to generate an url by a name which doesnt exist an you can see that he tries to generate an url with `/` as name. So this means that somewhere in your view file theres something like `route('/')` and this has to bee `route('index')`.

Answer (score 0):

When i look at you error screenshot which you've mentioned,i saw `Authenticate.php`
So i think you need to set home url over there

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class Authenticate extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they are not authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return string
     */
    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('index'); 
            // by default it's : return route('login'); you might have changed here  
        }
    }
}
```